# C# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize only top level?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have to work with an API which handles error responses like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "error message"
    }
}
```

And success respones like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

Error respones will always contain a code (integer) and a message (string), where as success respones can be different a lot ranging from just a few key-value-pairs to many objects and arrays.

I have created classes for every success "data" section and I can parse them successfully. Now I struggle with the simple part to determine if the response I got is actually an error or a success response.

My Idea was to create these classes:

```cs
    public class APIResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public APIResponseError Error { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class APIResponseError
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public int Error { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

And to serialize to the class `APIResponse`. This works only for error responses (kinda obvious) as the data responses are more than just a string which the `APIResponse.Data` actually is. My idea was to not deserialize the data field and just store it as a string in `APIResponse.Data`. Then, when I check and see that error is `null`, I would deserialize the `APIResponse.Data` property with the correct class. But how can I do this?

Comment: do you not receive appropriate HTTP Status Code with the response?

Comment: @SaiGummaluri sadly not, as the API is really inconsistent in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set type of `Data` property to `JToken`:

```
public class APIResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public APIResponseError Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public JToken Data { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize later with `ToObject`:

```
myCorrectResponse.Data.ToObject<ExpectedDataType>()
```

But I highly doubt that you will be sent any data in case of error response so I would recommend making `APIResponse` generic (where `T` could be object, array, etc.):

```
public class APIResponse<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public APIResponseError Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Which, in case of your example json will be used for example like:

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse<MyClass>>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a really good and simple solution. It is really easy to implement thanks to generics and in case of a successful response, it automatically gets parsed.